# List of Firestore Error Codes for Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When using Cloud Firestore in my Flutter application I want to use the error codes to return a localized error message to the user. However, I did not find a list of all the possible error codes that could occur. Is there a list like that or do I have to handle the errors differently?

Comment: Hey there! have you already taken a look at?[1] 
Can you also share a piece of code of what you have already tried?
Can you share an example of this might work with another database engine?

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code

Comment: @AntonioRamirez Thank you, that is what I looked for

Comment: Hey there, gladly to hear I could help somehow. Since stackoverflow is a community of questions and answers I have posted my comments as an answer so that it has more visibility. If my answer worked out for you, please accept it so that it may help other members that face the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the exception [codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code) from the firebase firestore documentation.

Answer (score 9):

You can see the list of possible exception codes at the [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md) or at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code). But, you need to change the code from uppercase to all lowercase and replace `underscore` with `dash`. For example:
`PERMISSION_DENIED` -> `permission-denied`

`NOT_FOUND` -> `not-found`

And so on.
Also, you need to catch `FirebaseException` instead of `PlatformException` in the new version of `cloud_firestore`.